# Different actions for Different events on same element using action helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a div which should execute the method **speak** on click:

**Corresponding Action Helper:**

```
<div {{action speak}}>Say</div>
```

If it were to execute the method **wiggle** on mouse enter:

**Corresponding Action Helper:**

```
<div {{action wiggle on="mouseEnter"}}>Say</div>
```

Now I want to combine both, I want it to execute **speak** on `click` as well as execute **wiggle** on `mouseEnter`

what would be the corresponding `{{action}}` helper ?

## Your Attention !

I know the following would work:

```
App.MultiEventView = Ember.View.extend({
  click: function(){
    /* some code */
  },
  mouseEnter: function(){
    /* some code */
  }
})

{{ view App.MultiEventView }}
```

But can we define multiple events using `action` helper instead of defining the view ?

Comment: According to https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/569 the core team is against adding multiple action support to Handlebars. A custom view is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not on the same div. {{action}} translates to a `data-ember-action` attribute on the element, and there's no mechanism for overloading that for more than one action.

What you can do is wrap your div in another div with the second action.